# Plot graphs in a loop from Pandas Groupby object

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

i'm quite new in pandas and i'm looking for a solution to plot several graphs with several series in a loop from a Groupby object.

below is the Groupby object

> > > gp_df = df.groupby(['Organe','Rang','Densite','Heure','Date']).mean()

```
>>> Organe  Rang  Densite  Heure  Date
      L       1     BD       AM     A        31.7520
                             PM     A        48.6480
                    HD       AM     A        42.4460
                                    B        79.0860
                                    C        13.3820
                             PM     A        46.0975
                                    B       115.1060
                                    C        60.9380
              2     BD       AM     A        62.9960
                             PM     A        62.9580
                    HD       AM     A        69.9040
                             PM     A        48.0920
```

And now i am looking for a solution to :
- create a new figure for each group of [Organe-Rang]
- for each group of [Organe-Rang] create a new plot (x=Date and Y = mean) for each group of [Density-Hour]

For example, the first figure (Organ = L and Rank=1) would have 4 plots: BD-AM, BD-PM, HD-AM and HD-PM. For each plot x = Date (could be just A or A,B,C) and y = computed mean

I tried to iterate on the Groupby object but i can't succeed in creating the different graphs correctly.

Hope you could help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas 0.16.1 you can use:

```
gp[['A','B','C']].plot(secondary_y=['D'],mark_right=False)
```

where `A,B,C,D` are column names you want to have on your graph ( column `D` is on right y axis)